# Cannot move out of borrowed content when using the struct literal update syntax: User { active: false, ..*user }

Tags: rust

I'm beginning in Rust and I like very much the syntax with `..` to [create an instance of another instance](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch05-01-defining-structs.html#creating-instances-from-other-instances-with-struct-update-syntax) but I don't know how to use it with a reference of an instance instead.

[Try it here.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=%23%5Bderive(Debug)%5D%0Astruct%20User%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20username%3A%20String%2C%0A%20%20%20%20email%3A%20String%2C%0A%20%20%20%20sign_in_count%3A%20u64%2C%0A%20%20%20%20active%3A%20bool%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20user1%20%3D%20User%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20email%3A%20String%3A%3Afrom(%22someone%40example.com%22)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20username%3A%20String%3A%3Afrom(%22someusername123%22)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20active%3A%20true%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20sign_in_count%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20user2%20%3D%20foo(%26user1)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20user2)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20foo(user%3A%20%26User)%20-%3E%20User%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20User%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20active%3A%20false%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20..*user%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D&run=1)

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct User {
    username: String,
    email: String,
    sign_in_count: u64,
    active: bool,
}

fn main() {
    let user1 = User {
        email: String::from("someone@example.com"),
        username: String::from("someusername123"),
        active: true,
        sign_in_count: 1,
    };
    let user2 = foo(&user1);

    println!("{:?}", user2);
}

fn foo(user: &User) -> User {
    User {
        active: false,
        ..*user
    }
}
```

Which gives me the error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:24:11
   |
24 |         ..*user
   |           ^^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

The funny thing is that it worked for me at some point:

```
fn reduce<'a>(state: &State<'a>, action: Action) -> Option<State<'a>> {
    match action {
        Action::LoadRoms { roms } => {
            let mut new_state = State { roms, ..*state };
            Some(new_state)
        }
        _ => None,
    }
}
```

[From here.](https://github.com/cecton/meldnafen-rust/blob/master/src/store.rs#L38)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `..expr` syntax moves all the missing member from `expr`. It *moves*. That means you generally can't use it with a reference, since you can't move out of a reference (you can "move" `Copy` types out of a reference though).

To solve you problem, you need to clone, in order to get a new full object you can move from:

```
fn foo(user: &User) -> User {
    User {
        active: false,
        ..user.clone()
    }
}
```

([link to playground](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=c3dacea150a98993c9308f59d5f55afb&version=stable&mode=debug))

The downside is that this also clone all members you don't need because you've already specified them. In this case it's fine since cloning `active` is a trivial operation (as it's just a boolean), however this would make an extra useless clone for `username`:

```
fn foo(user: &User) -> User {
    User {
        username: "foo".into(),
        ..user.clone()
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok makes sense thanks.... but then... why did it work at some point? XD That puzzles me

Comment: @Cecile It works in your second example because `roms` is the only non-`Copy` member of `State`, and `roms` is the element you're replacing, so it doesn't need to be moved. In `struct` update syntax, only the fields that are not explicitly set are moved. (If you added another field to `State` that was non-`Copy`, it would have the same issue `User` does.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanations

Comment: Cloning is not working, I still obtain a reference: `   = note: expected type User found type &User`

Comment: @Cecile you also need to make `User` clonable, otherwise you are only cloning the reference, which is pretty useless. Simply add `#[derive(Clone)]` as in the playground example.